# show amount field as sum of 4 input field multiply with its current price by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

```
<style>
        label.heading {
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        .payment-form {
            width: 300px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px #333 solid;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px;">
    <form action="payment.php" method="post" class="payment-form">
        <label for="packgprice" class="heading">$80 </label><br>
        Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes1" id="bikes1"><br><br>
        <label for="packgprice" class="heading">$90 </label><br>
        Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes2" id="bikes2"><br><br>
        <label for="packgprice" class="heading">$100</label><br>
        Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes3" id="bikes3"><br><br>
        <label for="packgprice" class="heading">$110</label><br>
        Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes4" id="bikes4"><br><br>

        <label for="firstName" class="heading">First Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"><br><br>

        <label for="lastName" class="heading">Last Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"><br><br>

        <label for="amount" class="heading">Amount (USD)</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"><br><br>

        <label for="email" class="heading">Email Id</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br><br>

        <div id="dropin-container"></div>
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit">Pay with BrainTree</button>

    </form>

</body>
```

I need to show amount filed as
(quntity1*price1)+(quntity2*price2)+(quntity3*price3)+(quntity4*price4)

by javascript or jquery withot page refresh

Please someone help for this issue

Comment: [this](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) will definitely help you. Give it a try on your own. If you will need help with it, update your question again with your tried code.

Comment: use jquery `keyup` to calculate your amount each time user enter a value for quantity field

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
<label for="packgprice" class="heading">$80 </label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes1" id="bikes1"><br><br>
<label for="packgprice" class="heading">$90 </label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes2" id="bikes2"><br><br>
<label for="packgprice" class="heading">$100</label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes3" id="bikes3"><br><br>
<label for="packgprice" class="heading">$110</label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" name="bikes4" id="bikes4"><br><br>
```

with:

```
<label for="packgprice" class="heading price-1" data-price="80">$80 </label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" class="trigger" name="bikes1" id="bikes1"><br><br>
<label for="packgprice" class="heading price-2" data-price="90">$90 </label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" class="trigger" name="bikes2" id="bikes2"><br><br>
<label for="packgprice" class="heading price-3" data-price="100">$100</label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" class="trigger" name="bikes3" id="bikes3"><br><br>
<label for="packgprice" class="heading price-4" data-price="110">$110</label><br>
Qunatity :<input type="text" class="trigger" name="bikes4" id="bikes4"><br><br>
```

and javascript for your task:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").on("keyup", function(){
        var amount_price = 0;
        for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
            if(parseInt($("#bikes" + i).val()) > 0){
                amount_price = parseInt(amount_price) + parseInt($(".price-" + i).attr("data-price")) * parseInt($("#bikes" + i).val());
            }
        }
        $("#amount").val(amount_price);
    });

});
</script>
```